# React js stripe payment add shipping info

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a payment component for my app using stripe. I have difficult to add the shipping info or properties into the stripe button:

in my payment.js

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from './axios';

let stripePromise;
const getStripe = () => {
  if (!stripePromise) {
    stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_...');
  }
  return stripePromise;
};

const Payment = () => {
      
  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <h1>Stripe Checkout</h1>
      <p className="checkout-title">Design+Code React Hooks Course</p>
      <p className="checkout-description">
        Learn how to build a website with React Hooks
      </p>
      <h1 className="checkout-price">$19</h1>
      </div>
      <form action="/payments-create" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Payment;
```

I found the doc for adding shipping info at https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/shipping#create-checkout-session-with-options using the code below in my index.js component. but I felt difficult how to integrate the code below in my payment.js so that i can have the shipping and delivery info within the stripe payment button?

index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production!
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/apikeys
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_...');

app.post('/payments-create', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA'],
    },
    shipping_options: [
      {
        shipping_rate_data: {
          type: 'fixed_amount',
          fixed_amount: {
            amount: 0,
            currency: 'usd',
          },
          display_name: 'Free shipping',
          // Delivers between 5-7 business days
          delivery_estimate: {
            minimum: {
              unit: 'business_day',
              value: 5,
            },
            maximum: {
              unit: 'business_day',
              value: 7,
            },
          }
        }
      },
      {
        shipping_rate_data: {
          type: 'fixed_amount',
          fixed_amount: {
            amount: 1500,
            currency: 'usd',
          },
          display_name: 'Next day air',
          // Delivers in exactly 1 business day
          delivery_estimate: {
            minimum: {
              unit: 'business_day',
              value: 1,
            },
            maximum: {
              unit: 'business_day',
              value: 1,
            },
          }
        }
      },
    ],
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: 'usd',
          product_data: {
            name: 'T-shirt',
          },
          unit_amount: 2000,
        },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: "/success",
      cancel_url: "/cancel",
      automatic_tax: {enabled: true},
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});
exports.api=functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

in App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Payment from './Payment';
import Success from './Success';
import Cancel from './Cancel';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import {Elements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
const  promise=loadStripe('pk_test_...');

function App() {
<Route path='/success'>
        <Header />
        <Success />
        </Route>
  
      <Route path='/cancel'>
      <Header />
      <Cancel />
      </Route>
   
     <Route path='/payment'>
          <Header />
          <Elements stripe={promise}>
            <Payment />
          </Elements>

        </Route>
```

This codes give me an error ("Cannot POST /payments-create")

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want to use requires a server-side integration. The idea is that you have your server that will create a Checkout Session via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) and pass all the relevant parameters.

Your integration though is incompatible. You're using a legacy integration that Stripe deprecated a while ago called "client-only Checkout" and that is limited and can't enable shipping options. The only solution is to switch to the server-side integration which requires having your own server.

Comment: I did have my own server from firebase, I just edit my question with my own server, however, i still have difficult to connect these two pieces of code together.

Comment: You are now creating the Checkout Session server-side. You need to completely remove the entire client-side code (which was trying to create a Checkout Session already). All you need to do now is redirect to the Session's `url` after creation. This is all covered in details in Stripe's docs: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart where they show you how to redirect `res.redirect(303, session.url);`

Comment: I did according to https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart and redirect res.redirect(303, session.url) in the index.js (server), and edit the payment.js, the edited above still doesn't work, and give me an error (Cannot POST /payments-create 404 (Not Found))

Comment: @Grace Hard to say unfortunately, your server-side code seems correct but maybe your overall code got out of sync between the client and the server?